# Go REST API not acessible from Apache2

Tags: go, https, apache2

Debian 9.11 box...

I have two REST APIs written in Go running on server on ports 8111 and 8112 (both as services) and an Apache2 server running on default port 80.

My Web application (written using Quasar/VueJs) is served by the Apache2.

My internet domain points to this box.

I cannot access the APIs using [www.mydomain.com:8111/..](http://www.mydomain.com:8111/..).

In fact, when I use these things by IP and without HTTPS everything worked. Now that I'm trying to use the domain name and HTTPS ("magically" provided by Cloudflare) I can't acess anything...

What am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing port 80? Does your services listen to port 8111 and 8112 of the external interface, or localhost only? Does your box allow access to those ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

On Apache `<VirtualHosts>` configurations:

```
<Location /api/userstatus >
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8111/userstatus
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8111/userstatus
</Location>
```

Incoming traffic uses HTTPS, internal API uses HTTP.